# Inserting from Text document to Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, text-files, bufferedreader

Hello I am trying to make a small program to get information from a text document and insert that information into a hashmap. The tricky part what I don't understand is how to differentiate the information so it goes into the fields I want it to in my hashmap.

Now you can say the text document I am going to be using has various "labels" already in place. For example, the text document has information displayed in the following format: 35=22, 20=0, 52=20180608-19:51:02.352, 56=ALPH

I am thinking of inserting all that information in a Hashmap type . I just want to differentiate the info, so that for example:

```
BufferedReader reader = 
 new BufferedReader(newFileReader("C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Documents\\pruebasx.txt"));

String line=reader.readLine();
Map<Integer,String> hm1 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
                    hm1.put(1, arg1)
                    hm1.put(2, arg1)
                    hm1.put(3, arg1)
```

Here 1 would read label 35 and put value 22, the hashmap value 2 would read label 56 and put value ALPH. How can I identify the information in this way? Also what happens if I have multiple lines in similar format, would they also be passed onto the hashmap or would I have to create a new one?

Comment: The `put(...)` method of `HashMap` does not "read" anything. You need to read the file line-by-line, separate the input by `=`, interpret the first value (left of the `=`) as key and the second value (right of the `=`) as value.

Comment: The separating would be done with regex I assume?

Comment: `String inputLine = ...;` [`String[] values = inputLine.split("=");`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: I think you'd want to split on `','` first to get the label=value pairs, then split each of those on `'='` to isolate the label and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your file can contain rows/line breaks. If not, just swap the `while` statement with `line = reader.readLine();`.

```
Map<Integer,String> hm1 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
String line;
// while there is a line to be read
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // we need to tokenize the line. the common separator is ", "
    // so that it what we shall split it by, to get an array of each value between ", "
    String[] tokens = line.split(",\\s"); //(in regex, \\s matches a whitespace such as a space)
    // if the space is unreliable, it can be made optional: line.split(",\\s?")
    // loop for each record
    for (int i = 0; i != tokens.length; i++) {
        // next we need to get the "data" portion of the record, which is after the '='
        /*
        ** we could use regex again
        ** i.e. tokens[i].split("=")[1] will be the "data"
        ** but as a general rule, if you can do it easily without regex, don't use regex.
        ** it might look innocent enough, but a lot goes on in a regex engine!
        **
        ** instead we just get the index of '=' in the string
        ** add 1 to move past it
        ** and then get the characters from that index onward
        ** i.e. tokens[i].substring(tokens[i].indexOf('=')+1)
        */
        //get the index at which the data starts in the string
        int dataIndex = tokens[i].indexOf('=') + 1;
        //get the chars from that index onward
        String data = tokens[i].substring(dataIndex);
        //insert it into the map
        hm1.put(new Integer(i),data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I tried this and it is exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `Properties` class.

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Documents\\pruebasx.properties"); 
pro.load(fr);                    
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,pro.getProperty(35));
map.put(2,prp.getProperty(56));
```

Comment: If you choose this way,you must use the format of the properties file.

Comment: Would the properties file be structured in the format: "35=2" or would it be structured in the format "35=?" ?